# how to find a solr doc which has a complete match of given search term but in different search fields

Tags: solr

I would like to find the documents which matches all the words of the given search term.

For example I search on below fields in solr.

1. ProductName
2. ProductDescription
3. ProductSummary

When I search for "My First Product", I should get the document which has either complete term in any search field  or if the match happened on more than one field in the document. i.e I should get first two documents in the results.

example data:

```
 {
   “ProductName”: “My”,
   "ProductDescription": “My First Product“,
   "ProductSummary": “Summary”
 },
 {
   “ProductName”: “My”,
   "ProductDescription": “First”,
   "ProductSummary": “Product”
 },
 {
   “ProductName”: “Product”,
   "ProductDescription": “First”,
   "ProductSummary": “Nothing”
 }
]  

How should I achieve that in solr?
```

Comment: You can have a catch-all copy field (in the examples this might be configured under the name `_text_`) and use `mm=100%` with the edismax handler or `q.op=AND`: https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh I created catch-all copy field (multi field) with the type text. Yes it is giving me results but it is giving more than expected results. As I asked in the above question when I search for "My First Product" (because each term should be there in the document fields, either in same field or in different fields) I wanted to get only first two results, but I am getting all three results because "Product" and "First" are available in third document as well. How to achieve this with catch all field?

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment, use `mm=100%` - which means that all query terms need to match, or `q.op=AND` to say that every term needs to be AND-ed together and not OR-ed.

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh , Right now my website search is using edismax with different query fields in qf with boosting parameters for sorting the results. Now I have to make sure the whole search term should be available in the document (either in same field or in different fields), this was achieved using catch all field with mm parameter. But is it possible to achieve this matching whole search term with boosting of particular fileds for sorting the results? I am thinking to use join on same collection, but not sure if it is correct way to do.

Comment: You can use the separate `boost`, `bq` or `bf` arguments (possibly multiple times) to boost certain documents matching your queries or apply a function boost. `boost` is preferred.

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh I observed that when I search for two words `ex: abc xyz` the`mm=100%` or `q.op=AND` only works when we use multifield in `qf` or the two words belong to same field if I use individual fields in `qf`. If I use individual fields in `qf` and searching for pharses which are from different fields then I am getting 0 results. Do we have any other alternative to make it work without multifields or something?

Comment: Create a second catch-all field as I mentioned in my answer. If you want to match across fields, add a field that have all the content you want to use for the match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a catch-all copy field (in the examples this might be configured under the name `_text_`).

You can then [use `mm=100%`](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/the-dismax-query-parser.html#mm-minimum-should-match-parameter) or `q.op=AND` to make sure that every term in your query gets matched when searching. `mm` requires either the `dismax` or the `edismax` (recommended) query parser (`defType=edismax`).